# Oracle does not choose the correct index in a dynamic query using SYS_CONTEXT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table consisting of three major fields: "begin_time", "end_time" and "login_name". To improve the query speed I have created a index on these three fields. Now I have a query that makes use of the `SYS_CONTENT` function like this:

```
select * from tbl1 R
where
begin_time <= TO_DATE(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_END_TIME'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
AND end_time >= TO_DATE(GREATEST(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'rptBeginTime'), SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_BEGIN_TIME')), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
and (
    SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME') = '*'
    or (
        login_name in (
            select regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
            from dual connect by level <= regexp_count SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The query works like this: when the input "RES_LOGIN_NAME" is a comma seperated list, it would search for records of proper login name within the date period. If the input is '*', then it would search for all records within the date period.

Functionally, this query works perfectly for me. If I replace all `SYS_CONTEXT(...)` to some concrete values, Oracle knows how to pick the correct index (use the correct index, with all three fields). However, in the above case with `SYS_CONTEXT`, Oracle still picks the correct index, HOWEVER from the "explain plan", I observe that it only picks the begin_time and end_time as the predicate for the index, excluding the "login_name".

I would like to know why Oracle excluded the login_name from the predicate when fitting it to the index, and also any method I could force Oracle to include login_name in the index?

**Additional information**
If I remove "SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME') = '*' or", then this query execute very fast.

Comment: Some general questions: how big is the table? How many users are there? What programming language is being used (if any) to call the query?

Comment: It is a table with > 10M rows. Only a few users (less than 10). It is a query in a general dashboard, without any programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is probably connected with the histograms on the begin_time and end_time indexes and the fact that Oracle cannot predetermine the results of function calls.

The first thing to understand is that using an index is not necessarily the best option, especially if the query already makes use of one index. There is an overhead in using an index - Oracle has to go to the index, fetch the index information and then use that to look-up the data blocks. If there are a lot of rows to be fetched, it is sometimes easier just to fetch the data with a full table scan.

Secondly, if you are already using another index it is even more difficult as Oracle cannot even use the second index to directly fetch the blocks; it has to do a hash join of the rows of each index and this can be expensive. Again, it might be better just to filter the rows from the second condition.

The way Oracle decides what strategy to use is to use the histograms in the indexes to count the number of rows that would be returned and to work out the most efficient strategy.

The problem is that if you use a function like `SYS_CONTEXT` Oracle really has no idea what value that function will return, so can't make an accurate estimate of how many rows the condition will select (unlike when you specify a literal value).

My first suggestion is to ask whether you are actually having a real performance problem (do you actually need to select on the login index). If performance is fine, assume that Oracle knows what it is doing.

If performance is not good, you could try adding hints to the select statement to force use of an index. For example:

```
select /*+ index(index_name) */ * from table_name;
```

See this article: [Oracle index hint syntax](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_index_hint_syntax.htm)

The other option is to pre-evaluate the `SYS_CONTEXT` function calls in your code (perhaps you only need to do this once) and then pass the output of these functions to your query as literals. This may or may not be practical depending on what environment and programming language you are using, but this method is very effective in getting the optimizer to work well.

If you can't do that, you could try tricking Oracle into thinking that login_name is always in the query. For example:

```
and
    login_name in (
        select login_name from dual where SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME') = '*'
        union
        select regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
        from dual connect by level <= regexp_count SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+'
        where SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_A', 'RES_LOGIN_NAME') <> '*')
        )
    )
```

Comment: You've point out one important concept that I've missed: Oracle do not know the value of "SYS_CONTEXT" in the query. So I guess it is the reason that although it picks the correct index but doesn't include all the fields (although I have included in the SQL). The performance really matters for me, if proper index is used, I could query the result within 2 seconds, but now it consumes around 2 minutes. Index hint doesn't work in this case, because oracle used the correct index, but just not include all the fields.

Comment: Based on your idea, I've tried some different kind of workaround and seems the performance is improved. One of the solution I've tried was to move the "login_name block" out and make it a "with" statement, with a /*+ MATERIALIZE */ hint.